# imagemagick can't find files inside subdirectory

Tags: zsh, imagemagick

this line is supposed to go into each subdirectory, combine every image in there to a pdf of the same name as the subdirectory, and move it to the parent directory

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && convert *.jpg(n) "$d.pdf" && mv $d.pdf .); done
```

this is the error

```
zsh: no matches found: *.jpg(n)
zsh: no matches found: *.jpg(n)
convert: unable to open image './dir/-0': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `./*/` as a glob, `$d` will contain something like `./dir/`, so you're going to run `convert *.jpg(n) ./dir/.pdf && mv ./dir/.pdf .`. Also note that `.` is the *current* directory, not *parent* (which is `..`).

Here you'd want something like:

```
for dir (./*(/)) (convert $dir/*.jpg(n) $dir.pdf)
```

Here, we're using the `(/)` *glob qualifier* to select files of type *directory* (change to `(-/)` if you also want to include *symlinks to directories* like with your `*/` approach).

You will get errors for directories that don't have non-hidden jpg files, but because we're using subshells, that only exits the subshell.

If you wanted to avoid the errors, you could check that there are jpg files in the first place like:

```
for dir (./*(/)) {
  files=($dir/*.jpg(Nn)) # N for nullglob
  (($#files == 0)) || convert $files $dir.pdf
}
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
for dir (./*(/)) (){(($# == 0)) || convert $* $dir.pdf} $dir/*.jpg(Nn)
```